Angular build error: Can't find stylesheet to import
I'm encountering an error while building my Angular application, even though the code works fine locally. The build process fails with the following error message:
35.36 - Building...
35.36 
84.96 Application bundle generation failed. [49.600 seconds]
84.96 
84.98 ✘ [ERROR] Can't find stylesheet to import.
84.98    ╷
84.98 26 │ @use '@material/feature-targeting/feature-targeting';
84.98    │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
84.98    ╵
84.98   node_modules/@material/line-ripple/_line-ripple-theme.scss 26:1                          @use
84.98   node_modules/@material/line-ripple/_line-ripple.scss 29:1                                @forward
84.98   node_modules/@material/line-ripple/_mixins.scss 24:1                                     @use
84.98   node_modules/@material/textfield/_text-field.scss 36:1                                   @forward
84.98   node_modules/@material/textfield/_mixins.scss 24:1                                       @forward
84.98   node_modules/@material/textfield/_index.scss 2:1                                         @use
84.98   node_modules/@angular/material/core/tokens/m2/mat/_form-field.scss 3:1                   @use
84.98   node_modules/@angular/material/core/tokens/m2/_index.scss 20:1                           @use
84.98   node_modules/@angular/material/core/tokens/_m3-tokens.scss 6:1                           @use
84.98   node_modules/@angular/material/core/theming/_definition.scss 6:1                         @forward
84.98   node_modules/@angular/material/_index.scss 7:1                                           @use
84.98   projects/<some_path_in_my_project>1:1  root stylesheet [plugin angular-sass]
84.98 
84.98 

If you have any workaround or temporary solution to this problem, please share.
Additional informations:

Angular version: 18.0.1
Angular Material version: 18.0.1
Node.js version: 20

Build work fine in local.
I just ran ng build <my_app> inside node:20-alpine docker container

I have the same problem wenn a github action build it. The error only occurs sometimes

See https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/27167
